# star wars API get request and building Command Line tool

Tags: python

I am working with a Star Wars API from http://swapi.co/api/. Here's the problem that I was working on for the *Star Wars API problem*. And the code works and prints out the exact output that I desired. I would like to see how turn this problem into a command line tool.

```
# You are a Logistics Coordinator for the Star Wars rebel forces and are responsible for planning troop deployments. 
# You need a tool to help find starships with enough passenger capacity and pilots to fly them.  

# Build a CLI tool that takes as its single argument the number of people that 
# need to be transported and outputs a list of candidate pilot and starship names 
# that are each a valid possibility. 
# Assume that any pilot can be a candidate regardless of allegiance. 
# Assume the entire group of passengers must fit in a single starship. 

# You may skip starships with no pilots or with unknown passenger capacity.  
# Your tool must use the Star Wars API (http://swapi.co) to obtain the necessary data.



# You may not use any of the official Star Wars API helper libraries but can use any other libraries you want 
# (http client, rest client, json).



# Example usage:

# $ ./find-pilots-and-ships 10

# Luke Skywalker, Imperial shuttle

# Chewbacca, Imperial shuttle

# Han Solo, Imperial shuttle

# Obi-Wan Kenobi, Trade Federation cruiser

# Anakin Skywalker, Trade Federation cruiser
```

[Python 3 solution](https://repl.it/@Jeffchiucp/twolargestklargest-3):

```
import sys
import requests
import json
import urllib.parse

#number of pages in JSON feed

def print_page(page_num, num_passenger):
    endpoint = "https://swapi.co/api/starships/?"
    type = 'json'

    #specifies api parameters
    url = endpoint + urllib.parse.urlencode({"format": type, "page": page_num})

    #gets info
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    # number_of_ship = json_data['count']
    if 'results' in json_data:
      for ship in json_data['results']:
          if has_pilot(ship) and has_enough_passenger(ship, num_passenger):
              print_pilots_on(ship)

def get_pilot_name(pilot):
    type = 'json'

    #specifies api parameters
    url = pilot

    #gets info
    json_data = requests.get(url).json()
    return json_data["name"]

def print_pilots_on(ship):
    for pilot in ship['pilots']:
       print(get_pilot_name(pilot), ship['name'])

def has_pilot(ship):
    if ship['pilots']:
      return True
    return False

def has_enough_passenger(ship, num):
    if ship['passengers'] != "unknown" and int(ship['passengers']) >= num:
      return True
    return False

def print_pilots_and_ships(num_passenger):

    page_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    # list to store names

    for page in page_list:
        print_page(page, num_passenger)


if __name__ == '__main__':
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your program is all contained in functions, you could use an `input + dict` to delegate function calls:

```
def get_pilots(arg1, arg2):
    #....
def print_pilots(arg1, arg2, kw1, kw2):
    #....

functions = {'get_pilots': get_pilots,
             'print_pilots': print_pilots}

func = None
while func is None:
    ans = input().split()
    func = functions.get(ans[0], None)

ans = ans[1:]
args = []
kwargs = {}
for i in ans :
    if '=' in i:
        kw, arg = i.split('=')
        # split keyword args
        kwargs[kw] = arg
    else:
        args.append(i)

# call function returned from dict with args and kwargs and print result 
print(func(*args, **kwargs))
```

Now you can do something like this when `input()` is called:

```
>>> get_pilots arg1 arg2 
# result from function call
```

And with keyword arguments:

```
>>> print_pilots arg1 arg2 kw1=arg kw2=arg
```

The call is translated into:

```
print_pilots(*[arg1, arg2],
             **{kw1: arg, kw2: arg})
```